# Need to process an MS word document using Map Reduce/Apache Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have been working out on a Hadoop/MR project which needs to work on a MS word document and generate some output out of it. The document is in format as below -

> **Paragraph1**
>
> .......
>
> .......
>
> **Paragraph2**
>
> .......
>
> .......

The problem is two pronged -

1. Which InputFormat works right for MS word couments, i understand that TeXtInputReader should not work here, please correct me if i am wrong.
2. I need to parse the document paragraph wise and not line wise, so do i need to write a custom RecordReader for this? and if yes, any pointer for this?

Any help on this will be really helpful.

Comment: A quick help on this will be really appreciable...

Comment: You are right you will need to write the record reader. You can refer to http://poi.apache.org/text-extraction.html for parsing the doc/docx files.